# Confusing flow error when dealing with multiple promises and callbacks

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, flowtype

I'm adding flow to a project, and I've run into an error I can't figure out. Here's some code that produces the same error:

```
type user = {
  id: string,
};

const thing = function(): Promise<user> {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    var p1 = new Promise(innerResolve => {
      getData(data => {
        innerResolve(data);
      });
    });
    Promise.all([p1]).then(result => {
      resolve(result[0]);
    });
  });
};

const getData = function(callback) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    callback({});
  }, 1000);
};
```

[Link to this code on Try Flow, where you can read the error.](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBArgzhATlAvFA3gKClAlgEwC4o5hFcA7AcwBpMBfAbk0wGMB7C0qYAC0qqooAMxgVWwXJwAUASmIAFROwC2uBAB54SAHwZsURBGAxEFKBQgB3KEtXqI0o3HYAbAG7QUerDhzuAQ2QwAEYhSxs7NQRpSktEACUIFw8vHwM-KCpjABEA4ADpfHyA1HTMzLikJJTPIpLZZgqoekaMlrbMqIcAOgDXV2kAbVCAXVkevggKJ2SYV2Ay-WbnNzrneeAhgAZxpr9W-cOGZjZObmzgPIKhUXFJGVZ+1wAjANYAa1llkmMAFVwKgg7BgwGkciWvj8TwGb0+0nQxxw9BoUBC2wxbSYQA)

In my application, the getData function goes out to a database to get the object. And the type of what it returns in the callback can only be this specific:

```
{
  [key: string]: string,
}
```

So it could be called with an empty object, like in the example. If you replace that line with:

```
callback({id: 'working'})
```

there are no type errors. But I can't do that in my application.

Another strange thing is that I can remove this whole block:

```
Promise.all([p1]).then(result => {
  resolve(result[0]);
});
```

and that also makes it pass the flow test.

And the one thing I'd think would fix this issue -- refinements -- don't resolve the issue.

```
    if (typeof data === 'object' && typeof data.id === 'string') {
      innerResolve(data);
    } else {
      throw new Error('bad db response');
    }
```

I haven't been able to figure out any way to get flow to accept this code, without changing something that I can't actually change (like replacing the database code with a simple return).

Can anyone explain the error I'm seeing, and why I'm triggering it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are explicitly setting the return type of `thing` function to `Promise<user>`, and that's why you get the error since your `callback` passes the parameter `{}` which is NOT a `user`

I don't know what your specific requirement is or why you are using a `timeout` but if the return type *can* be something that is NOT `user`, meaning `any` you can make the return type: you can set the return type to `Promise<user|any>`

> You explicitly set the return type, so you have to return that return type.

Comment: Isn't adding `|any` basically just giving up? If I try `|false` and some refinements, same issue. [example link](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBArgzhATlAvFA3gKClAlgEwC4o5hFcA7AcwBpMBfAbk0wGMB7C0qYAC0qqooAMxgVWwXJwAUASmIAFROwC2uBAB54SKAB8RAQwA2CAHwZsURBGAxEFKBQgB3KEtXqI063HZGAbtAo5lg4OP4GyGAAjEJOru5qCNKUTogAShC+AUEhlmFQVDYAIgbABtL4ZQaoeTgAkPW4wlDSoJDsLVXlqChoAOTsAEYAVhAS-VAAZFM84BCdUN0GAHQEvQOk5NT9shYFB3gUaZnZgZXVssyHOPRQECbQoTc4qUinfufCxgiy+Qf0f63K7-egggqJTwrYxGaQAbRiAF1ZCs+BAKN4sjAjMBavsDj5Pl4fNjgHCAAzI65hMHU2kMZhsTjcIrAUo9NCicSSGSsGFDAysADWe2eCGAABVcCoFjBgNI5Hjnjg+UYjALhdJ0PTbjQoNFyYaQUwgA)

Comment: Not if you're explicit about it and know for sure that a different data type will be passed. why not just pass a user like `{id: "someID"}` to your callback? `callback({id: "someID"});` You say your `getData` will fitch the data from an API, so where is the issue?

Comment: I meant for the `getData` function to just be a placeholder. It should usually respond with a user, but actually accesses the database so there's a chance something else will come back. I did explain what type I can expect as a response in the main post.

Comment: but that's just it, you said "there's a chance something else will come back" so if you know what that is, make a `type` for it. If you don't, you have no choice but to use `any`. Also, remember, it's all going to transpile to JS and js, at runtime is not statically typed. Ie, the type won't matter to your transpiled code.

Comment: I think I'm getting what you're saying. What I still don't get -- why didn't my refinement strategy work? Or throwing an error when the returned value wasn't a user? I thought both of those would stop a non-user result from getting returned.

Comment: What was your refinement strategy?

Comment: It's in the example link in the first comment of the thread, and the original post. `if (typeof data === 'object' && typeof data.id === 'string') {`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159264/discussion-between-ahmed-musallam-and-fnsjdnfksjdb).

Answer (score 0):

indeed, an empty object is not of type `user`. Instead of returning an empty object when you have no match, is to return an empty array, and make your `thing` function return an array.

This changes the semantics: `thing` returns a promise of an empty array when there is no match, or an array with one element when there is.

```
const thing = function(): Promise<user[]> {
```

... and the callback call should pass an array with zero or one elements:

```
callback([]);
```

Your sample code could also be reduced to this, but I assume you have other code that made you write it like you did:

```
type user = {
  id: string,
};

const thing = function(): Promise<user[]> {
  return new Promise(getData);
};

const getData = function(callback) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    callback([]);
  }, 1000);
};
```

On [Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBArgzhATlAvFA3gKClAlgEwC4o5hFcA7AcwBpMBfAbk0wGMB7C0qYAC0qqooAMxgVWwXJwAUASmIAFROwC2uBAB54SANoBdAHwZsURBGAxEFKBQgB3KEtXqI0quYAiAQ2BfZzJhYOLmAod2BvXyFRcUkZVi8AG0SAIy9WAGtZYxwEYAAVXBUIdhhgaTlUIywcHATktMzpfX8TehooAEYABl7WpiA)

Comment: I can't change what getData returns -- it's standing in for a function that accesses a database. And when I tried to replicate what you did, but by detecting a non-user object and return an empty array in the callback, and it didn't work.